# How to interpret this parsing error of the image variable that was rendered in the django template in heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

The error says (ImageFieldFile' object is not subscriptable) I wanted to call an image url using an image variable in the html django templates.

I thought it was a date-util version error as i have been seeing other users recommend using date-utl version 1.5 which heroku only works with even after deprecating the date-util 2.8 to v 1.5 it still didnt work.

```
SyntaxError at /
invalid syntax (parser.py, line 158)
```

this is where the error occured

```
src="{{ tweet.user.profile.image.url }}"
```

Error was this

```
SyntaxError at /
invalid syntax (parser.py, line 158)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://meawesometwitterapp.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 2.2.2
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value:    
invalid syntax (parser.py, line 158)
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py in <module>, line 27
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python37.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 29 Jul 2019 09:32:44 +0000
```

I cant intepret the error in the production heroku django app

Comment: We need a bit more of the surrounding code for parser.py to help you.

Comment: I solved it! I just needed to upgrade the Date-util. Sorry for giving the partial information.